# Adding multiple boolean arrays together

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I have this method that adds two 2d boolean arrays together. So for a given cell, if any array is `true` for that cell, the cell in the resulting array is set to `true`.

```
private boolean[][] addBooleanArrays(List<boolean[][]> arrays) {
    boolean[][] result = new boolean[8][8];
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            for (boolean[][] b : arrays) {
                if (b[i][j] == true) {
                    result[i][j] = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I'm feeding this method 16 boolean arrays that I know contain `true` and `false` values but I am getting a null pointer exception  at the if statement. I can't see why though, maybe I'm missing something. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `null` check to ensure that a particular `b` isn't `null`:

```
if (b != null && b[i][j] == true) {
```

A for-each loop like you're using will still return each value in `arrays`, even if the value is `null`.

Comment: Yeah but my arrays only contain true and false I know that for a fact

Comment: Most definitely, since `boolean` is a primitive type and can't be set to `null`. But I'm talking about making sure that `b`, which is a 2-d `boolean` array, isn't `null` (see the difference?)

Comment: Ok I added that check and a `b` is null. But I can see how it can be null. My `arrays` List only has boolean[][]?

Comment: That's because arrays (whatever their dimensions; in this case 2-d) are objects, so they can be set to `null`.

Answer (score 1):

A row in the input array is null instead of being a `boolean[8].`

Comment: I thought booleans initialise to false

Comment: @Clay You have to realize that there are 9 objects involved.  Each array is an object, so a `boolean[][]` is an object that could be null.  Since this is a 2-D array, each element of the array is itself an object, another array, so any of those array elements could also be `null`.  (And if you had said `new boolean[8][]`, the array elements would be initialized to `null`.)  Those last eight arrays are the arrays of `boolean`, though, and I think those are indeed initialized to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some b[i] is null that causes the exception, I suggest you checking the code generating elements of arrays.